# Rails 3: Sending Mail with Attachment - corrupted file after first send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to implement a  real simpel newsletter.
Therefor I can select as much recipients I want.

To that newsletter I can attach a file. This works great for the first mail. All next mails have corrupted attachments (1 byte size).

actionmailer:

```
def send_newsletter(recipient,subject,content,file)
    @content = content

    if file
      attachments[file.original_filename] =  {
        :content=> file.read, 
        :mime_type=> file.content_type
      }
    end

    mail(:to => recipient, :template_name => "deliver_newsletter",
             :subject => subject).deliver!
  end
```

applicationcontroller:

```
  def create
    @customers = Customer.where("CHAR_LENGTH(email) > 0")
    @recipients = params[:sent_to]
    @subject = params[:subject]
    @content = params[:content].html_safe
    @file = params[:file]

    if @recipients
      @recipients.each do |mail_recipient|
        Newsletter.send_newsletter(mail_recipient,@subject,@content,@file)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bills_path, notice: "everything works fine" }
    end
  end
```

and finally the form for sending newsletters:

```
    <%= form_tag ('/newsletters'), :multipart => true do %>
            <%= t 'views.newsletter.to_recipient' %>:<br>
            <%= select_tag 'sent_to', options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, 'email', 'name'), :multiple => true, :class => 'sent_to' %><br><br>
          <%= t 'views.newsletter.subject' %>:<br>
            <%= text_field_tag 'subject' %><br><br>
          <%= t 'views.newsletter.content' %>:<br>
            <%= text_area_tag 'content', "".html_safe, :size=>"20x8" %><br><br>
<%= t 'views.newsletter.attachment' %>:<br>
<%= file_field_tag 'file' %><br><br>
          <%= submit_tag t('views.buttons.newsletter_send_now'), :class => "btn btn-primary", :disable_with => t('views.buttons.newsletter_sending') %>
    <% end %>
```

another small question: why is "delay" from the "delay_jobs" gem not working here? All other mails can be sent by typing "Newsletter.delay.send_newsletter(...)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because `file.read` leaves you at the end of the file with nothing left to read. I would add a `file_contents = file.read` in your ApplicationController, and then pass that in as an additional parameter to each `send_newsletter` call, assuming the file is small.

Comment: the solution is as simple as effective. thanks for that great hint! Now it's working!